# How to find the corresponding column number from excel sheet column name in PHP?

Tags: php

MS Excel columns has a pattern like A, B, C, … ,Z, AA, AB, AC,…. ,AZ, BA, BB, … ZZ, AAA, AAB ….. etc. In other words, column name "A" should return 1, column “B” should return 2, column “AA” should return as 27.

Given a column name as appears in an Excel sheet, return its corresponding column number.
i.e

```
   A -> 1
   B -> 2
   C -> 3
   ...
   Z -> 26
   AA -> 27
   AB -> 28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findnum($col){

        $colval = ord($col);
        $len = strlen($col);

        $num = 1;
        if($len==1){
            $num += $colval-65;
        }
        else {
            $flen = $len-1;
            $sec = str_split($col);
            foreach ($sec as $key) {
                $ordval = ord($key);
                $num += ($ordval-65);   
            }
            $num = $num+(26*$flen);

        }
        echo $num;  

    }
```